# PHP Nested Array - Output sub-array contents and array name

Tags: php, arrays, nested

Consider this nested array:

```
$link = array(
 'Level 1' => array(
   'Monthly' => array( 
    'note' => 'Note 1 1',
    'link'  => '1.1.com',
    ),
   '6 Month' => array(  
     'note' => 'Note 1 6',
     'link' => '1.6.com',
    ),
 ),
 'Level 2' => array(
   'Monthly' => array( 
    'note' => 'Note 2.1',
    'link'  => '2.1.com',
    ),
   '6 Month' => array(  
     'note' => 'Note 2.6',
     'link' => '2.6.com',
    ),
 ),
```

How would I gracefully use a `foreach` to achieve the following:

```
if $var = 'Level 1' output 

  <a href="1.1.com" title="Note 1 1">Monthly</a>
  <a href="1.6.com" title="Note 1 6">6 Month</a>
```

I'm suspecting I might need to do a loop inside a loop? I can iterate through the array, but am having trouble figuring out how to call the name of the sub-array...

Comment: To think, I put the vars in arrays thinking it would be easier... bah

Comment: I'm thinking I should refactor the 'Monthly' into the same level as the note and link vars... in a numeric array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$key = 'Level 1';

$link = array(
 'Level 1' => array(
   'Monthly' => array( 
    'note' => 'Note 1 1',
    'link'  => '1.1.com',
    ),
   '6 Month' => array(  
     'note' => 'Note 1 6',
     'link' => '1.6.com',
    ),
 ),
 'Level 2' => array(
   'Monthly' => array( 
    'note' => 'Note 2.1',
    'link'  => '2.1.com',
    ),
   '6 Month' => array(  
     'note' => 'Note 2.6',
     'link' => '2.6.com',
    ),
 ),
);

if(isset($link[$key])) {
    foreach($link[$key] as $array) {
        print_r($array);
    }
}
?>
```

RETURNS

```
Array
(
    [note] => Note 1 1
    [link] => 1.1.com
)
Array
(
    [note] => Note 1 6
    [link] => 1.6.com
)
```

I check to see if it is set first and then run a foreach on the set key to print out what you need.

#### EDIT:

```
if(isset($link[$key])) {
    foreach($link[$key] as $key => $array) {
        print $key;
        print_r($array);
    }
}
```

Which returns

```
Monthly
Array
(
    [note] => Note 1 1
    [link] => 1.1.com
)
6 Month
Array
(
    [note] => Note 1 6
    [link] => 1.6.com
)
```

Comment: Yes! This is the step (`$link[$key]`) I was f-ing ripping my hair out over... so simple once I see it. This is why I love SO

Comment: great. you got @OliverSamson43's intention.

Comment: But wait... how do I ouput the name of the arrays? (Monthly and 6 Month...)

Comment: I know, right? @fluke -- I'm so messed up in code right now, I don't know which way is up...

Answer (score 0):

I think using nested loop in this case is graceful.

Just use two foreach.

Comment: So, when I'm in the second nested loop, how do I get the parent of that loop?

Comment: in every foreach loop you get a $key and a $value. $key and $value in the parent loop are from the parent. inside the parent loop, you can do a foreach to the value to get sub data.

Answer (score 0):

that's how it'd look like if you're trying to define the arrays within the main array

```
    foreach ($link  as $sub_array) {
        //do something
        foreach ($sub_array as $sub_of_sub) {
            // do something and so on
        }
    }
```